# Are there laws in ecology?

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology

Are there clearly defined ecological laws, as in the science of physics? If not, why is this the case?

Comment: first rule of biology: there is an exception to every rule, including this one.  But seriously this article may help you. http://www.ecology.info/laws-population-ecology.htm

Comment: I think this is really more of a question of philosophy rather than science. You can read a bit about the meaning of a scientific law on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_science My personal opinion is that the reason people don't talk about laws as much in biology is because laws are too small/specific to be the most interesting answer to a biological question. In physics, a law is something that you are able to reduce a broad phenomena to. In biology, it's rare outside of mathematics to be able to reduce to one statement that describes an entire phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

**What is law and what is ecology?**

I always find the definition of "law" a little hard to grasp but maybe only because I am a mediocre philosopher. To me, I don't quite understand the difference between a theory (a theory is not a hypothesis in science) and a law.

It is also hard to know what exactly you would consider being part of ecology and what you would be considered part of evolutionary biology, agriculture or paleoecology / paleogeology and those disciplines are very much related. Here are a few concepts that I don't if they would qualify for an answer

- [General latitudinal diversity gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitudinal_gradients_in_species_diversity)
- The concept that [symbiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiosis) is more a rule than an exception (it also comes with the discovery that mitochondria are/were endosymbionts).
- [Theory of natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_selection)
- [Positive and negative feedbacks in glacial period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_age#Positive_and_negative_feedback_in_glacial_periods)
- [Geographical area law/hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitudinal_gradients_in_species_diversity#Geographical_area_hypothesis)
- [Parental effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_effect)
- [Adaptive radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_radiation)
- [r/K selection theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecology#r/K_selection_theory)
- Theory of island biogeography
- ...

**Are there science that create more laws than others?**

I am really not qualified to answer this question but I would tend to think that in ecology, there is a lot of important discoveries that lead to a conceptual rephrase or to a reconsideration of the relative importance of different concept or to the realization of a single fact, more than to the phrasing of a law per say.

**Laws in ecology**

Here are a few concepts in ecology that are often being called law.

- [Liebig law of the minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebig%27s_law_of_the_minimum)
- [Ten percent law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_efficiency#Ten_percent_law)
- [Allee effect law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allee_effect)
- [Square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law), [allometric scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allometry) and the [metabolic theory of ecology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_theory_of_ecology)
- [Ecological systems theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_systems_theory)

as well as all the laws regarding population growth such as

- [Malthusian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusian_growth_model), [Verhulst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Fran%C3%A7ois_Verhulst) and [Lotka-Voltera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) laws.